# How to select from Table rather than View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an old inherited database that has a user table and a system view with the same name, different schema.

For some reason when I select from the table, even when qualified with schema name, it seems to select from the system view.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the table definition:

[image]

This is the error shown when I select from the table:

[image]

Is anyone able to shed some light on what is/might be happening here?

At this stage, I'm just trying to get a 10+ year old system stable and can't rename anything just yet, so I need to figure out what's happening with the code and db, but this step... step 1, login, has me stumped.

If it helps, this was a SQL 2000 database that was upgraded to 2008 database that was upgraded to a 2016(??) database.  Took a couple of steps to do that, but now I'm stuck with this bit.

Comment: are you able to select the top 1000 records by right clicking on the dbo table?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Sorry @DaleK, it seemed clearer to show the issue than copying and pasting text..

Comment: @sacse, no, the Select top 1000 doesn't work either.. and if I right click on the table to edit the top 1000 (or whatever it says) SSMS bombs out and crashes.

Comment: @Ads, Oh, it seems like an upgrade issue. Is there any way you can see the dbo table data?

Comment: Its much clearer posting your code and results as formatted text.

Comment: From SQL 2012 you cannot do this anymore. See last chapter (example)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/system-compatibility-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: So does `select object_id(N'dbo.sysLogins'), object_id(N'sys.logins')` return the same object_id in both columns?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, it returns -205 and NULL respectively..

Comment: @Ads sorry, I mis-typed. I meant `select object_id(N'dbo.sysLogins'), object_id(N'sys.syslogins')` (the extra `sys` is important).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I get the same ID for both -205.

Comment: @NenadJ. That seems to be the behaviour I'm seeing..  it seems in 2008 it would have been fine, but upgrading beyond this broke things.
At least I have an answer..  Thanks.