# How to rename one of two objects that have same name in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that has been upgraded from 2000 to 2008 to 2016 and I have ended up with two objects of the same name, one a compatibility system view and one a user table.

The objects are:

- `[dbo].[sysLogins]` - user table
- `[sys].[sysLogins]` - view

If I select from each object, specifying the schema, I get the results from the view both times. See the screenshots in this question where if I select from the [dbo].[sysLogins] table, the field names should be "UserID", "LoginName", "...", but I'm actually getting "sid", "status", "..."
[How to select from Table rather than View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68751673/how-to-select-from-table-rather-than-view)

If I use the sp_rename command to rename the system view, I get:

```
exec sp_rename 'sys.sysLogins', '_RENAMED_sysLogins'
```

> Msg 15225, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 418 [Batch Start Line 15]
> No item by the name of 'sys.sysLogins' could be found in the current database 'DB-NAME', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.

If I use the `sp_rename` command to rename the user table, I get:

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.sysLogins', '_RENAMED_sysLogins'
```

> No item by the name of 'dbo.sysLogins' could be found in the current database 'DB-NAME', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.

As per the comments in the `sp_rename` stored procedure, I tried to specify the @objtype param of 'object'

```
[6]  Here are the valid @objtype values.  They correspond to system tables which track each type:
'column'  'database'  'index'  'object'  'userdatatype'  'statistics'
```

I ran the following and got these results:

```
exec sp_rename 'dbo.sysLogins', '_RENAMED_sysLogins', 'OBJECT'
```

> Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 401 [Batch Start Line 17]
> Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong.

Am I wasting my time trying to rename one of these objects?

Is there are a "hardcore", "hack the db" type of way to do this rename directly in a system table somewhere?  There is just this one object that clashes.

Am I better off going back to the original SQL Server 2000 version of the database, rename the table, then do the upgrade process again?

Comment: I can reproduce your issue in SQL Server 2019 just by creating a table `dbo.syslogins` in `tempdb`. SQL Server treats it as the `sys.syslogins` table regardless of specifying the `schema` name. This looks to be a bug in Sql Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to transfer the table data into a new **identical/clone** table (by switching partitions) and drop the syslogins table… [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1d891a6b513b9724bebeb314a3cdf692)

```
select top (100) object_id as userid, name as username
into dbo.syslogins
from sys.all_objects
go
select t.name, c.* --columns
from sys.tables as t
join sys.columns as c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where t.name = 'syslogins'
go
select * from dbo.syslogins
go
-- Clone
create table renamesyslogins(userid int not null, username sysname not null)
go
alter table dbo.syslogins switch to renamesyslogins
go
-- drop table dbo.syslogins
```

Comment: Let me see if I read your steps correctly:
1. create an arbitrary dbo.syslogins table with different fields to sys.syslogins
2. select rows from sys.tables and sys.columns to prove that the new table has been created.
3. select from dbo.syslogins which returns from the system view sys.syslogins
4. creates a new "dbo.syslogins" table called "renamesyslogins" with the necessary fields.
5. "move" dbo.syslogins to renamesyslogins table.

Comment: ..@Ads .. that’s right. You need steps 4&5 (a clone table with the same structure as your dbo.syslogins) The arbitrary dbo.syslogins table (with two columns) in the answer was just for demonstration.